# React-native - iOS - 34 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: react-native, architecture, duplicates, symbols, arm64

Everytime i run my App with "XCode" it failed with the error "34 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64".
I use the xcode version "14.1". I cannot find a solution for this problem.

Additional: I use the library "react-native-beacons-manager" and add "libRniBeacon.a" in "link Binary With Libraries".

Does anybody know how i can solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

rm -rf node_modules

cd ios

rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods

removed derived data

Quit Xcode

cd ..

npm install

cd ios

pod install

run the project from XCODE

Comment: First, thank you for your hint. It works but after this i have a "new" error. RNiBeacon.m -> "'React/RCTBridge.h' file not found". Have you an idea why?

Comment: @iSaBo Did you manage to fix this error: "'React/RCTBridge.h' file not found" ?

Comment: @yuvalchen yes, you have to link the library manually